# Where can I download the stock clock apk for LG G3?

Tags: apk, alarm, lg-g3

I deleted the stock clock app on the LG G3 (Model D855) without knowing that I need it for the Quick Circle Case to correctly display the Clock Faces when the lid is closed.

Do you know a place where I can download the stock APK file, it goes something like "com.lge.alarmclock", the easy access from Google Drive is not longer working:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3dApvWjgNoKVmU5cjlUMFdwbW8/edit?usp=sharing
*not working*

I tried doing the hard reset but the app did not get back.

Or if anyone would be so kind to back it up for me, I would deeply appreciate it.

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: did you actually delete the app from /system/priv-app or did you just remove the circle clock from the lock screen?

Answer (score 1):

A "hard reset" would not change the `/system` partition, which is where the .apk originates. Since you deleted the system app, I'm going to assume that you have root access. After installing the .apk, I recommend manually pushing it to `/system/priv-app/` (command: `adb push LGAlarmClock.apk /system/priv-app/`, replacing LGAlarmClock.apk with the full path to the .apk. *Alternatively*, you can change it from a user app to a system app (via an app like [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) if you install it from PackageInstaller, but **I highly recommend pushing it to `/system/priv-app/` from adb**. [Here is a link to `LGAlarmClock.apk`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7-FM1u-QGwNbVY0UmFmTnRIdGM/view?usp=sharing), pulled from [the latest stock lollipop 5.0 build on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g3/development/stock-t2961073).

Comment: Hi, just a note that the link to the Drive is dead now. It'd be better if you could fix it. Thanks.